# Using easylist with chrome declarativeNetRequest

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I want to use [easylist](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/blob/master/easylist/easylist_adservers.txt) to block ads in a chrome extension. Someone suggested me to use `declarativeNetRequest` api to achieve the task but I'm not sure on how to proceed. I've readed the docs and as I understand, I need to define one or more rules that are used to block the requests.

I've added the necessary permissions to the manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extDescription__",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus",
    "proxy",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [{
      "id": "ads_ruleset",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "ads_rules.json"
    }]
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16.png",
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "128": "icons/128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

and in my background script I'm fetching the list usin axios:

```
lat adsBlacklist = [];

axios.get( 'https://github.com/easylist/easylist/blob/master/easylist/easylist_adservers.txt' ).then( (response) => {
 adsBlacklist.push(response.data);
});
```

The first problem I need to solve is how to remove unnecessary rows and words from the list, in the list there is the `$third-party` word appended at the end of some urls, and also are present two unnecessary rows with the word `! Third-party` and at the beginning of the list there is `! Non-flagged (Revolving ad servers)` word they will not be useful for my scope and I don't know how to remove them.

The second problem is about list converting and usage. After getting it (and parsed by removing the unuseful informations?), I need a way to use the urls patterns inside a ruleset that unfortunately doesn't support an array of rules but accept only a string for the matching. At the moment I've this json file defined as my default ruleset:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action" : { "type" : "block" },
  "condition" : {
    "urlFilter" : "||01dbf3a452b6.com^",
    "domains" : ["<all_urls>"],
    "resourceTypes" : ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
  }
}
```

Since I don't want to write manually all the rules, I want to use the `updateDynamicRules` method, but I'm not sure on how to proceed with it, I've searched for an example in the samples section of the chrome api documentations but I found nothing. How I can create all the needed rules automatically for each url that is in the list? Can anyone help me with the implementation by providing an example please?

Answer (score 1):

The format followed by declarativeNetRequest rulesets is different from easylist, so you'd have to convert the ruleset to the format required by declarativeNetRequest.

Also note that the maximum number of dynamic rules is currently bounded to [5000](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeNetRequest#property-MAX_NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_RULES), so the approach of using dynamic rules for easylist might be a non-starter.

I'd suggest writing a python script to parse the easylist format and converting it to a declarativeNetRequest static ruleset. This can be part of the extension packaging step.

There seem to be several examples of filter list parsers on [github](https://github.com/search?q=easylist%20parse). In fact, there seems to be a project which converts Adblock Plus filter lists to chrome.declarativeNetRequest rules. See [link](https://github.com/kzar/abp2chromerules).